# What's up with generic disapproving diplomatic statements from other civs in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

So every so often I'll get a message from one of the AI players, something along the lines of "If it isn't my favorite City-State" or something similar. Usually my options for response are along the lines of "You'll pay for this" or "We're sorry this has caused a divide between our people" or "Very Well".

What's up w/ this? Is there some way I can find out what the other Civ just did?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These sort of messages are typically received from civilizations that are *hostile* to your own. I believe the idea behind those is

1. To let you know that civilization is hostile to you.
2. To give you a hint about the areas in which you are lacking (e.g. if they say you are uncivilized, it indicates your culture output is too low).

I'm pretty sure that among the two response options, one is just to slightly increase the hostility and one to slightly decrease it, basically giving you some influence about the future of the relations.

Comment: Can I ask why you would want a civilization to be more hostile towards you? The only thing I can think of is that it might make declaring war have a smaller penalty with your reputation to the rest of the world (I assume declaring war with a hostile civ is ok, but declaring war with your ally is considered un-honourable)

Comment: @Akusete indeed, that's basically the only reason I can think of for that. Sometimes it just feels good to threaten them, though :)

Comment: In previous games, what other nations complained to you about depended on the other nation. IE Egypt saying you're 'uncivilized' might not mean you're low on culture in general, but they you're low on culture compared to Egypt. (And in Civ 4, who wasn't?) Sadly, I have no idea how to figure out which way the Civ 5 actually works, since these messages are so random.